# Wpf binding is not async

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-community-toolkit

I'm working on a .Net 6.0 wpf project which uses the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm nuget package for mvvm.  All the binding are working but not asynchronously, every time a property is updated the ui freezes until the binding is complete

A usercontrol binds to the viewmodel like:

```
d:DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}"
```

In the usercontrol I have a button and a textbox

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Update" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand, IsAsync=True}"  />
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LogText, IsAsync=True}" />
```

The viewmodel looks like:

```
public sealed class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
```

In the viewmodel I have a LogText property

```
private string _logText = string.Empty;
public string LogText
{
    get => _logText;
    set => SetProperty(ref _logText, value);
}
```

The command is declared as:

```
public IAsyncRelayCommand UpdateCommand { get; }
```

and initiated in the constructor

```
UpdateCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(Update);
```

The update method is something like:

```
private async Task Update()
{
    var countries = await ApiService.GetAllCountries();
    foreach (var country in countries)
    {
         LogText += $"{country} updated!"
    }
}
```

As mentioned all the bindings are working but when Update() is triggered the UI waits and freeze until the method is completed. The textbox only updates after Update() is completed.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a misconception. `{Binding UpdateCommand, IsAsync=True}` only means that the UpdateCommand property getter is called asynchronously, not that the command is executed asynchronously. Setting `IsAsync` is pointless here. Besides that, your `Update()` method does not perform any asynchronous operation.

Comment: Also, `d:DataContext` only sets a design-time DataContext, not one at runtime.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the answer.  I forgot to mention that the countries are populated by an api service.  var countries = await ApiService.GetAllCountries();  I've updated the question

Comment: The "UpdateCommand" property from the point of view of Binding is a normal CLR property. In this case, applying IsAsync to it makes no sense, since there is no «long» logic in the property body.
And the fact that a property returns a command instance only matters after the binding assigns the resulting value to the target property. The interpretation of the received value will depend on the logic of the target property (in this case, Command).

Comment: `LogText += ...` is still executed in the UI thread. Depending on how often it is performed and how expensive it actually is, it may of course "freeze" the UI. You may certainly first add all log entries to a local string variable and update `LogText` only once. Setting `IsAsync` on the TextBox.Text Binding is of course also pointless.

Comment: If you are experiencing lags when calling the `UpdateCommand` command, then this may be due to the implementation of `AsyncRelayCommand`. Without knowing the details of the implementation, it is difficult to answer the reason. And could you answer - what is the approximate number of elements in the `countries` collection?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, it helped me a lot!  Seemed a non async method in the api was blocking

Answer (score 0):

Variant of method implementation if LogText creation takes VERY LONG time and/or the number of countries is VERY LARGE:

```cs
private async Task Update()
{
    var countries = await ApiService.GetAllCountries();

    int refreshInterval = 500; // LogText Property Refresh Interval
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(LogText, 1000); // Some initial capacity

    stopwatch.Start();
    foreach (var country in countries)
    {
        builder.Append(country);
        builder.Append(" updated!");
        if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > refreshInterval)
        {
            LogText = builder.ToString();
            stopwatch.Restart();
        }
    }
    LogText = builder.ToString();
}
```